# Deep Linking PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApp that uses SharePoint as a data source. When a user submits a form, a PowerAutomate flow sends them an acknowledgement email with a link directly back to their item. The link is properly constructed, with the correct item ID in the URL. However, when the PowerApps app launches from the link in email, it ALWAYS opens the very first item in the gallery on the home screen, regardless of the parameter in the URL.

I was following the guidance of this article: [PowerApps Deep Linking](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-deep-linking/)

I have the timer on my home screen set to:

```
If(Not(IsBlank(Param("Record"))),Navigate(DisplayScreen, Cover,LookUp(Event_Requests, ID = Value(Param("Record")))))
```

with a timeout trigger of 600ms.

Comment: I've not yet had a need to use deep linking but Shane Young has a good video on how to do it. Perhaps something in his video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5Pi5P2YKds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue is that when you deep link to the item with a given form, you have to specify in the Item parameter for the form that if you are coming from a URL with a parameter, lookup the item, rather than use the gallery.selected value. For example:

```
If(!IsBlank(Param("Record")),First(Filter(MySharePointList,ID=Param("Record"))),Gallery1.Selected)
```